# Wallet Pass auto update web service using aws api gateway

Tags: node.js, aws-api-gateway, wallet

I am working on a web service to update Apple Wallet passes using AWS Lambda/API gateway/NodeJS. The Apple wallet hit the api to get update pass but each time I am getting following error:

*encountered error: Received invalid pass data (The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid.)*

I have tried the same URL in the browser to get the pass. The pass is downloading every time and its opening a valid pass every time. But its not working when Apple wallet hit the URL. I have tried same URL in Postman it gives me base64 instead of binary data.

I have tried to achieve the same functionality with NodeJS and deployed on heroku, its working properly with Wallet(also gives binary in Postman). But I need to use AWS Lambda/API gateway/NodeJS.

I am not sure, if AWS changing something while delivering binary data.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: What else do you see in the console logs for the iPhone?  Do you have the WWDR developer certificate installed in your lambda app?

Comment: Here is the entire log: {
    "logs": [
        "[2017-08-31 12:43:04 +0530] Get pass task (pass type pass.com.xxx.xxx.xxx, serial number xxxxxxxxxx, if-modified-since (null); with web service url https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xxx/) encountered error: Received invalid pass data (The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid.)"
    ]
}
The WWDR is isntalled. The same pass is working when webservice provided through heroku.

Comment: Have you set the content-type header correctly?

Answer (score 4):

I just experienced this and spent hours trying to diagnose what was happening.

For anyone using AWS API Gateway & Lambda for their PassKit web service endpoints, there's a major "gotcha" (at least as of the date of my response) with how API Gateway's logic determines whether it needs to convert a response from base64 ==> binary.

If you inspect the request headers from Apple Wallet / PassKit, you'll see that the `Accept` header is `*/*`.

API Gateway apparently iterates through the items in the request `Accept` header and determines if there is a match with any of the **Binary Media Types** you've defined under **Your API Name > Settings**.  It will use the first match it finds and then, as you'd hope, convert the base64 string (from Lambda) to binary.

Here's the crazy part -- if you define `application/vnd.apple.pkpass` as one of your "please convert to binary" media types, requests from Apple Wallet / PassKit ***will not work***.  Why?  Well, AWS (for whatever reason...) hasn't programmed `*/*` to match ***any*** type ... it will literally *only* match `*/*`.

As a result, the `Accept` header's `*/*` will **not** match with `application/vnd.apple.pkpass` and your base64-encoded .pkpass response (from Lambda) will not be converted to binary, causing PassKit to choke + report errors.

---

TL;DR -- there is some goofiness with AWS API Gateway.  To return PassKit pass data successfully, you need to add `*/*` (*not* `application/vnd.apple.pkpass`) under **Your API Name > Settings > Binary Media Types**.

Comment: Hello i have tried with above setting but no luck.

Can i know in which content type we have to send pkpass file from AWS lambda in base64 or utf-8 from buffer pkpass file